# Prove that $\mathbf{F}^3 = U \oplus W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

This is an example from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right":

> Suppose $U$ is the subspace of $\mathbf{F}^3$ of those vectors whose last coordinate equals $0$, and $W$ is the subspace of $\mathbf{F}^3$ of those vectors whose first two coordinates equal $0$:
> $$U = \{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbf{F}^3 | x,y \in \mathbf{F}\} \text{ and } W= \{ (0,0,z) \in \mathbf{F}^3 | z \in \mathbf{F}\} $$
> Then $\mathbf{F}^3 = U \oplus W$, as you should verify.

I am a little confused about how to go about showing that an arbitrary vector in $\mathbf{F}^3$ can be written as a unique sum of vectors in $U$ and $W$. At frst I was thinking that the goal to be proved was $\exists ! u \in U \exists ! w \in W ( u + w = v)$, but this seemed overly complicated. Is my approach below correct?

Proof: Let $v$ be an arbitrary vector.

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $v \in \mathbf{F}^3$. Then we can write $v$ as $v = (x,y,z)$ for $x,y,z \in \mathbf{F}$. Let $ u = (x,y,0) \in U$ and $w = (0,0,z) \in W$. Then $v = u + w$, so $v \in U + W$. Now let $u' \in U$ and $w' \in W$ be arbitrary such that $u' + w' = v$. Then $u' = (a,b,0)$ and $w' = (0,0,c)$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbf{F}$. It follows that $u' + w' = (a,b,0) + (0,0,c) =v = (x,y,0) + (0,0,z)$. Therefore, $a=x$, $b = y$, and $c=z$. It follows that $u=u'$ and $w=w'$, so $v \in U \oplus W$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $v \in U \oplus W$. Then we can choose a $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v = u + w$. Since $u \in U$, $u = (a,b,0)$ for $a,b \in \mathbf{F}$. Since $w \in W$, $w = (0,0,c)$ for $c \in \mathbf{F}$. Since $a,b,c \in \mathbf{F}$ and $v = u + w = (a,b,c)$, it follows that $v \in \mathbf{F}^3$.

Since $v$ was arbitrary, $\mathbf{F}^3 = U \oplus W$. $\square$

Comment: Your $(\leftarrow)$ part is unnecessary : $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^3$ (by definition), so $U+W$ must be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{F}^3$, the exercise ask you to proof that this is in fact a direct sum of subspaces and the sum is $\mathbb{F}^3$. Hence your $(\rightarrow)$ gives already a complete proof (but the last line should be "so $U+W=U\oplus W$" instead of "so $v\in U\oplus W$")

Comment: @wormsgo Thank you for your reply! Why should it be $U + W = U \oplus W$? I was trying to show that $\mathbf{F}^3 \subseteq U \oplus W$.

Comment: It was in the $(\rightarrow)$ portion that you proved (up to a certain weakness) that $F^3 \subseteq U\oplus W$. In $(\leftarrow)$ you proved $U\oplus W \subseteq F^3$, and that is unnecessary because it is true by definition as $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $F^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It follows that $u' + w' = (a,b,0) + (0,0,c) =v = (x,y,0) + (0,0,z)$. Therefore, $a=x$, $b = y$, and $c=z$.

How do you get from $(a,b,0) + (0,0,c) = (x,y,0) + (0,0,z)$ to $a = x, b = y, c = z$?

It is certainly true - indeed practically obvious - but the very thing that makes it obvious is missing from your argument, despite your tossing out all sorts of other details at the same level. It looks more like you knew it was true, but not why, so you bluffed by just stating the result you wanted.

Comment: Should that line just be $u' + w' = (a,b,0) + (0,0,c) = (a,b,c) = v = (x,y,0) + (0,0,z) = (x,y,z)$?  Then $(a,b,c) = (x,y,z)$.

Comment: Yes. The fact that $(a, b, 0) + (0, 0, c) = (a, b, c)$ and similarly for the other side, and the fact that $(a,b,c) = (x, y, z)$ if and only if $a = x, b = y, c = z$ is what makes it obvious. What you wrote was correct, but the missing $(a,b,c) = (x, y, z)$ middle step when you covered so many other more petty details was a bit jarring.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!